# How I render content page to another html page

Tags: django, jinja2

I have already base.html page. How I can get my specific contact page information into my home page with jinja

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understating your question correctly, within your `home.html` you can use the include tag `{% include 'contact.html' %}` to have that bit of contact information be displayed directly in your home page from another template. For example:

Within your `home.html`

```
<body>
    ####
    <!-- Home page information being displayed already -->
    ####

    <!-- To include your contact page information -->
    {% include 'contact.html' %}
</body>
```

Within your `contact.html` only the section where you have the contact information will be necessary and not the entire contact page, for example:

Instead of having

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
     <section>
         <!-- Other elements with the contact information -->
     </section>
 </body>
```

You will only use the section below within your `contact.html` file.

```
<section>
    <!-- Other elements with the contact information -->
</section>
```